# Disabling user interaction for subview interferes with event handling for superview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

`CustomView` contains a subview, `SubView`, which implements a tap handler. However, for this implementation, `SubView` should ignore taps and let `CustomView` handle them.

The code below is supposed to achieve this, but setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false prevents taps on `SubView` from cascading to `CustomView`. Shouldn't `CustomView` still receive tap events if `SubView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to false?

The Apple documentation says setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` causes events to get ignored, not that the view will swallow them so superviews don't receive them.

```
// CustomView class, which is a subclass of UIView

// Handle taps
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doTap))
addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

// Add SubView
view.insertSubview(SubView, atIndex: 0)
SubView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Updated code (`doInit` is called since `buttonTapped` is invoked on taps) but still not working:

```
class CustomButton : UIButton, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    private func doInit() {
        ...
        // Handle taps
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
     }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SubView` will still receive the taps, but it will ignore them and it will stop there. If a view has `userInteractionEnabled` set to false, it will block touches that are meant for parent views.

My guess is you want to add this gesture recognizer delegate:

`func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool`

This will allow your parent view to receive touches at the same time as your `SubView`.

Comment: there are two gesture recognizers. the code above is for CustomView, so it is handling tap gestures. the problem is SubView has its own gesture handler, and it overlaps with CustomView so is apparently intercepting tap events on CustomView. so it's standard behavior for SubView to not propagate the taps? the apple documentation says setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false just ignores the events, not that it will swallow them?

Comment: You might find this helpful :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Specifically `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool`

Comment: so you're saying `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` should fix the problem? if so, and if it's expected behavior for the subview to swallow events and not pass them to the superview, please update the answer as it could help future swift learners. definitely not clear from the docs!

Comment: Well, it might fix your problem yes. Basically, when the system decides to detect a touch, it goes through all the subviews until it finds the first one that says `hey there, I'll take that!` So in your case, the `SubView` is doing that.

If you use the delegate methods, you might be able to pass that through to the superview

Comment: ok will try, but please update the answer because your comments are useful and highlight information not contained in the apple docs for `userInteractionEnabled`

Comment: do you have any sample code for how to do this if SubView is a UIButton and CustomView is a UICollectionView? UICollectionView and UIButton both have native functions for managing taps already, so you just override those?

Comment: updated the code with your suggested answer, but it appears the function isn't getting called even though the delegate is being set. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Laynemoseley's answer, this is the relevant bit from [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html):

> In iOS 6.0 and later,
>   default control actions prevent overlapping gesture recognizer
>   behavior. For example, the default action for a button is a single
>   tap. If you have a single tap gesture recognizer attached to a
>   button’s parent view, and the user taps the button, then the button’s
>   action method receives the touch event instead of the gesture
>   recognizer. This applies only to gesture recognition that overlaps the
>   default action for a control, which includes:
>
> A single finger single tap on a UIButton, UISwitch, UIStepper,
>   UISegmentedControl, and UIPageControl. A single finger swipe on the
>   knob of a UISlider, in a direction parallel to the slider. A single
>   finger pan gesture on the knob of a UISwitch, in a direction parallel
>   to the switch. If you have a custom subclass of one of these controls
>   and you want to change the default action, attach a gesture recognizer
>   directly to the control instead of to the parent view. Then, the
>   gesture recognizer receives the touch event first. As always, be sure
>   to read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines to ensure that your app
>   offers an intuitive user experience, especially when overriding the
>   default behavior of a standard control.

It seems the only solution is to override the gesture recognition and allow simultaneous gestures to get recognized.